# Facing problem while performing basic STL vector program

Tags: function, vector, stl

I am trying to implement a basic STL vector program but I am getting an error I can't understand and can't find a convincing solution either.[Here is the image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAyzn.png)

Here is the error:

*****no suitable conversion function from "__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator>>" to "int" exists*****

Also, if someone can, please explain me the problem too so that I can prevent this in future?

Comment: That code is too long to put into the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element), you'll see that `max_element` returns an iterator to the maximum element in the sequence.

That's not an `int`; when you try to assign it to an `int`, it fails, and gives you a message telling *exactly why* it's failing.